# python 3 pyQT4 Display image with multiply blend mode or with alpha

Tags: python, image, qt, blend

I'd like to set a image on top of my QT app with a multiplier blend mode (using the image as a filter), is it possible ?
The other solution that could work for me is to use a separate image in grey-scale and use it as an alpha. 
I think this is potentially possible with QGraphicsPixmapItem but I am not sure at all how to use it.

Any help much appreciated
thanks